# WP7/Expression Blend: Load different image

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, windows-8, expression-blend

I am trying to make a simple card game. I have loaded all 10 cards in my project and what I want to do is, if I click a button, I want to 'display' a specific card. How do I do that with a good programming practice.

What I can do is, make 10 StoryBoard and load the ones that I like whenever I click that button. But that is not a good practice. I want something like a method call or something, in which I just call the image file with an ID or by its 'filename'.

Please help.
Thankyou

Comment: Look into behaviors and triggers from thevBlend SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one Storyboard and change the Target of that Storyboard every time you click on a specific button. So for example, let's say that you have cards: 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6.

If you click on the button that says: "2" (the 2 card) then the following code will make your Storyboard target that specific control:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetName(animation, 2Card);
```

Where animation is a Timeline object and 2Card is the name of the control which you want to animate.